# MySql Group By and order by date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my table data:

```
id      page_id     time            created
=======================================================
1       1           00:15:00        2020-11-05 09:55:54
2       1           00:25:00        2020-11-10 07:35:24
3       2           00:10:25        2020-11-06 06:15:20
```

and here is the MySql query:

```
SELECT
  a.* SUM (a.time) AS time
FROM
  `activity` AS a
GROUP BY a.page_id
ORDER BY a.created DESC;
```

The desired result is to have the latest record showing on top, but instead, Im getting first record being on top;

Like:

```
2       1           00:25:00        2020-11-10 07:35:24
3       2           00:10:25        2020-11-06 06:15:20
```

instead I'm getting this:

```
1       1           00:15:00        2020-11-05 09:55:54
3       2           00:10:25        2020-11-06 06:15:20
```

Comment: You can't sum(time). You can instead convert time to seconds, sum that, and then convert it back to time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the latest record per `id`, as defined by `created`. If so, you need to filter rather than aggregate.

In MySQL 8.0, I would suggest window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*,
        rank() over(partition by page_id order by created desc) rn
    from activity a
) a
where rn = 1
order by created desc
```

In earlier versions, you can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from activity a
where a.created = (
    select max(a1.created) from activity a1 where a1.page_id = a.page_id
)
```

Comment: thanks but this partially works,. As soon as I add SUM(), it only shows 1 record

Comment: @Alko: you don't need `sum()` to get the results that you want. This produces the results that you showed for your sample data.